# Как хранить информацию в сервисе Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой что нужно передать информацию с одного компонента в другой, так как они не связаны, нельзя это сделать с помощью ViewChild и т.д., потому думаю надо сделать сервисом, каким образом можно передать и хранить информацию в сервисе?

Comment: Да вроде там все просто. Поле в сервисе и записывать\считывать данные оттуда. Что конкретно не понятно? Или нужно чтоб данные при обновлении в одном компоненте сразу обновлялись в другом?

Comment: Да, забыл сказать: данные приходят с сервера в 1 компонент, после чего он должен записать в сервис информацию, после чего надо что бы и 2й компонент эту информацию использовал

Comment: Ну буду копировать в ответ статью, приведу просто ссылку. Если что то непонятно тогда пишите. http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: Впринципе так и думал сделать, но думал есть что-то правильнее, спасибо большое!)

Comment: ну есть еще ngRx